# MPMoviePlayerController detecting single tap or long tap on NEXT button

Tags: ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

When I tap MPMoviePlayerController NEXT button , the UI turns black . How to identify if we touched NEXT just one time or if its a long tap . Do we have any delegates or notification for the same. ?

Answer (score 0):

Using **button action, it is not possible to identify that user just press one time or its a long tap**.
But if you gestures then it can be identify.
Using `UITapGestureRecognizer, UILongPressGestureRecognizer`  you can identify what you want.